# XSLT format-number function not formatting

Tags: xslt, numbers, format

I need to format a value to a specific format, but it doesn't appear as though its supported.

I want to use:

```
format-number($value, '####,##,##,##0')
```

but the value returned when trying this is `'###,###,##0'`

So if I `$value = '123456789'` I want to have the value output as `1,24,56,789` but I am getting `123,456,789`.

Are there limitations on what formatting you can do?

If you go to [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog) and enter the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>123456789</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>123456789</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>

</catalog>
```

and then the following xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:variable name="TestFormat" select="'###,##,##,##0'"/>
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="format-number(price, $TestFormat)"/></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

you can see that I am not getting the desired format. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11599696/36305

Answer (score 1):

The grouping separator `,` is only respected in its first occurrence from the right after the decimal separator. This is because [W3C specifies](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#format-number) that the *format pattern string is in the syntax specified by the JDK 1.1 DecimalFormat class.* [Looking at that class](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java/javanut/ch29_09.htm) reveals that it has an integer grouping size property, hence variable group sizes throughout the format cannot be modelled by that class.

Therefore, when writing `###,##,##,##0`, the grouping size is set to three (number of digits between the rightmost grouping separator `,` and the end of the format string, and when writing `###,##,##,0`, there will be a grouping separator between each digit.

If you *really, really* want to do this in XSLT without any external formatting tools/functions, you can probably craft something up by using the `string-length`, `concat` and `substring` functions and inserting the group separators manually.

**Update:** These statements are only valid for XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Your answer is correct for XSLT 1.0, but wrong for XSLT 2.0, which allows irregular grouping positions.

Comment: @MichaelKay: Thanks for pointing that out; I extended my answer to mention that, too. I was automatically assuming XSLT 1.0 as that's what was used in the OP's stylesheet.

Comment: There's another thing I would point out. XSLT 1.0 refers to the JDK 1.1 *specification* of DecimalFormat, not to the *implementation*. IIRC there's nothing in the specification that says the grouping positions in this pattern should be ignored; the fact that one JDK implementation ignores them is neither here nor there.

Comment: @MichaelKay: Hmm, doesn't the JDK 1.1 specification of `DecimalFormat` encompass the public interface of that class? If so, the public interface defines that there is exactly one grouping size integer, which also means that there can be no different grouping sizes throughout one format. Of course, this can only be seen in the class interface, but then, there's nothing in the `DecimalFormat` specification that allows us to assume that the string representation of a format and the API representation could be differently powerful. How is this usually handled when referencing ambiguous specs?

Comment: @MichaelKay: Unfortunately, the JDK 1.1 specification doesn't seem to make this clear; only versions starting at [JDK 1.1.1](http://www.tns.lcs.mit.edu/manuals/java-1.1.1/api/java.text.DecimalFormat.html#_top_) have added the remark *The grouping separator is commonly used for thousands, but in some countries for ten-thousands. The interval is a constant number of digits between the grouping characters, such as 100,000,000 or 1,0000,0000. **If you supply a pattern with multiple grouping characters, the interval between the last one and the end of the integer is the one that is used**.*

Comment: I don't recall the exact history. I do remember that it was embarrassing that successive releases of Java kept "refining" the specification, in many cases adding rules that legitimized the bugs in the implementation. That's why in XSLT 2.0 we redefined format-number without reference to the JDK specification, and made the decision not to incorporate the "bugs" such as this one.

Comment: @MichaelKay: Glad to hear so; kudos for that and thanks for the clarification :-)

Answer (score 1):

For 8 and 9 character strings, the following would work:

```
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(price,1,1)"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(price,2,1)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(price,4,1)"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(price,5,2)"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(price,7,3)"/>
        <xsl:if test="string-length(price) &lt; 9">
          <xsl:value-of select="0"/>
        </xsl:if>
      </td>
```

Depending on your intent, the "if" block might need to be moved or altered to accomplish slightly different formatting.

Answer (score 1):

It's really time you moved to XSLT 2.0. With the current release of Saxon your code produces this output:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
      <table border="1">
         <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Artist</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Empire Burlesque</td>
            <td>12,34,56,789</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Hide your heart</td>
            <td>12,34,56,789</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```